# Why is the Output is skipping statement of gets(&char*)

Tags: c++, string, char, gets

In the code below I have a class called `Market`. With the data members and functions as shown. When the function `shopkeeper(market &m , int i)` is called ,  The compiler executes the the printing of "Name" and "Price" without taking the `Name` from user by `gets()`.

```
class market
{
    public:
    char item;
    double price, tax, total;
public:


   market()
    {
        char* item;
        price=0;
        tax=0;

    }
    void shopkeeper(market &m, int i)
        {




                cout<<" Item number "<<i<<"\n ";
                cout<<" ----------- "<<"\n";
                cout<<"Name         ";
                gets(&(m.item));
                cout<<" Price        "<<endl;
                cin>>m.price;
                cout<<" Tax          "<<endl;
                cin>>m.tax;

        }
```

The output us as follows:
[image: The output]

Answer (score 1):

`item` is a single char. If you read documentation of `gets`, that function receives a pointer to buffer you have to allocate, big enough to fit input, or an Undefined Behavior would happen.

Also, gets is a function which should no longer  be used in C++. It also was removed from recent versions of language. You should use `std::string` and read it from `std::cin` like everything else.

Comment: Then what modifications should I make to my code to make it work?

Comment: Note that types `char item;` and `char* item;` are incompatible with one another. Might be worth mentioning in the answer.

Comment: @Chipster his code was mis-formatted that part fell out of 'code' block. `&(item)` and `char *` are absolutely compatible. It's just a buffer of a single char , so it can fit a zero length string. :P